# onclick works only on first element and doesn't work after first click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove elements as they are clicked closed. Any elements in any order.

But when I click close only the first element gets removed and when I console log the class that is being shown after clicking on other closing buttons it shows the class that is removed already.

```js
function removeContent() {
  let classes = document.querySelector('.pane').classList;
  classes = String(Array.from(classes).slice(1));
  console.log(classes);
  document.querySelector('.' + classes).style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
}

.remove-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: darkred;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pane horse">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent()">[x]</button>
    <h3>Horse</h3>
    <p>The horse is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus. It is an odd-toed ungulate mammal belonging to the taxonomic family Equidae. The horse has evolved over the past 45 to 55 million years from a small multi-toed creature, Eohippus, into the
      large, single-toed animal of today.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane donkey">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent()">[x]</button>
    <h3>Donkey</h3>
    <p>The donkey or ass (Equus africanus asinus) is a domesticated member of the horse family, Equidae. The wild ancestor of the donkey is the African wild ass, E. africanus. The donkey has been used as a working animal for at least 5000 years.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane cat">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent()">[x]</button>
    <h3>Cat</h3>
    <p>The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often
      valued by humans for companionship and for their ability to hunt vermin.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not removing any elements, you're just hiding them with display: none

Comment: where you have `document.querySelector('.' + classes).style.display = "none";`
you should use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the current element to the function using `this`.

```js
function removeContent(el) {
  el.closest("div.pane").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
}

.remove-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: darkred;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pane horse">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent(this)">[x]</button>
    <h3>Horse</h3>
    <p>The horse is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus. It is an odd-toed ungulate mammal belonging to the taxonomic family Equidae. The horse has evolved over the past 45 to 55 million years from a small multi-toed creature, Eohippus, into the
      large, single-toed animal of today.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane donkey">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent(this)">[x]</button>
    <h3>Donkey</h3>
    <p>The donkey or ass (Equus africanus asinus) is a domesticated member of the horse family, Equidae. The wild ancestor of the donkey is the African wild ass, E. africanus. The donkey has been used as a working animal for at least 5000 years.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane cat">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent(this)">[x]</button>
    <h3>Cat</h3>
    <p>The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often
      valued by humans for companionship and for their ability to hunt vermin.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can add the event listeners with Javascript instead, which will automatically bind the this value as the element itself.

```js
function removeContent() {
  this.closest("div.pane").style.display = "none";
}
document.querySelectorAll('.remove-button')
   .forEach(btn=>btn.addEventListener("click", removeContent));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
}

.remove-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: darkred;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pane horse">
    <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    <h3>Horse</h3>
    <p>The horse is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus. It is an odd-toed ungulate mammal belonging to the taxonomic family Equidae. The horse has evolved over the past 45 to 55 million years from a small multi-toed creature, Eohippus, into the
      large, single-toed animal of today.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane donkey">
    <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    <h3>Donkey</h3>
    <p>The donkey or ass (Equus africanus asinus) is a domesticated member of the horse family, Equidae. The wild ancestor of the donkey is the African wild ass, E. africanus. The donkey has been used as a working animal for at least 5000 years.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane cat">
    <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    <h3>Cat</h3>
    <p>The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often
      valued by humans for companionship and for their ability to hunt vermin.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hiding the elements by setting the display to none, actually remove them. Call your function by passing `this` to it, then remove the parent:

```js
function removeContent(elem) {
  elem.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
}

.remove-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: darkred;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pane horse">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent(this)">[x]</button>
    <h3>Horse</h3>
    <p>The horse is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus. It is an odd-toed ungulate mammal belonging to the taxonomic family Equidae. The horse has evolved over the past 45 to 55 million years from a small multi-toed creature, Eohippus, into the
      large, single-toed animal of today.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane donkey">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent(this)">[x]</button>
    <h3>Donkey</h3>
    <p>The donkey or ass (Equus africanus asinus) is a domesticated member of the horse family, Equidae. The wild ancestor of the donkey is the African wild ass, E. africanus. The donkey has been used as a working animal for at least 5000 years.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane cat">
    <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeContent(this)">[x]</button>
    <h3>Cat</h3>
    <p>The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often
      valued by humans for companionship and for their ability to hunt vermin.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        function removeContent() {
            event.target.parentElement.style.display="none"
    }
```

You can just take the event target's parent element and set it's display to none.

Answer (score 1):

You should select all the `.remove-button` elements and apply them an `onclick` event listener. When an item is clicked, you can hide its parent element (with [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.remove-button').forEach(removeButton => {
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 470px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  background: #edf5e1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px #c4df9b;
}

.remove-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: darkred;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pane horse">
    <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    <h3>Horse</h3>
    <p>The horse is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus. It is an odd-toed ungulate mammal belonging to the taxonomic family Equidae. The horse has evolved over the past 45 to 55 million years from a small multi-toed creature, Eohippus, into the
      large, single-toed animal of today.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane donkey">
    <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    <h3>Donkey</h3>
    <p>The donkey or ass (Equus africanus asinus) is a domesticated member of the horse family, Equidae. The wild ancestor of the donkey is the African wild ass, E. africanus. The donkey has been used as a working animal for at least 5000 years.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane cat">
    <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    <h3>Cat</h3>
    <p>The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often
      valued by humans for companionship and for their ability to hunt vermin.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```